# Mongo, Mongoid join data from different models in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm adapting a Ruby on Rails application to work with MongoDB instead of PostgreSQL. I have this 2 class:

```
module Cms
  class Content
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Orderable

    field :title, type: String
    field :position, type: String
    field :text_body, type: String
    field :expiration_date, type: Date
    field :active, type: Boolean, default: false

    validates :title, :text_body, presence: true

    orderable base: 0

    belongs_to :cms_content_category, class_name: 'Cms::ContentCategory'

    scope :ordered, ->() { order(position: :asc) }
    scope :not_expired, ->() { any_of({ expiration_date: nil }, { :expiration_date.gte => Date.today }) }
  end
end


module Cms
  class Submenu
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Orderable

    field :title, type: String
    field :position, type: String
    field :external_url, type: String
    field :open_as, type: String, default: '_self'
    field :active, type: Boolean, default: false

    delegate :url_helpers, to: :'Rails.application.routes'

    validates :title, presence: true

    validates :external_url, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |obj| obj.cms_content_id.nil? }
    validates :cms_content_id, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |obj| obj.external_url.blank? }

    orderable base: 0

    belongs_to :cms_content, class_name: 'Cms::Content'
    belongs_to :cms_menu, class_name: 'Cms::Menu'

    scope :ordered, ->() { order(position: :asc) }

    def url
      self.external_url.present? ? self.external_url : url_helpers.content_show_path(self.cms_content_id)
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that I don't know how to adapt the following SQL query to work with MongoDB.

```
scope :active, joins("FULL JOIN contents ON contents.id = cms_submenus.content_id")
               .where("cms_submenus.active IS TRUE AND (
                        (cms_submenus.content_id IS NOT NULL AND ((contents.expiration_date >= :today OR expiration_date IS NULL) AND contents.archived IS NOT TRUE)) OR
                        (cms_submenus.external_url IS NOT NULL AND cms_submenus.external_url <> '')
                      )", today: Date.today)
```

This scope has to be called from Submenu model.

Someone has an idea on how to solve this problem?

I'm using Rails 4.2.0 with Ruby 2.2.0 and Mongoid 4.0.2 with MongoDB 2.6.8.

thank you

Comment: You have to understand that with mongoid or other ODM type products on top of MongoDB that this is not "really a join" as it is done is SQL terms. It is an "emulation" of a join for "convenience only", that actually runs "additional queries" to appear to fetch the data as "joined". You cannot have conditions spanning collections. That is because the underlying truth here is that MongoDB "does not do joins".

Comment: Redesign your schema so that you don't need that JOIN. Generally this involves a combination of denormalization (which requires you to write the code to copy data between collections and keep those copies synced) and embedding.

Comment: We've wrote a small example with JSONiq where we can switch from MongoDB to PostgreSQL and vice versa without changing any query: http://www.28.io/blog/virtual-database-between-mongodb-and-postgresql/ You might find this helpful.